# Box iOS SDK: No on.progress call back for previewWithCallbacks

Tags: box-api

When downloading a file, I'm not getting an on.progress callback so am not able to display a progress bar.  Works fine for file uploading.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Pete

```
BoxFile *boxFile = (BoxFile *)boxObject;

[boxFile previewWithCallbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks> on)
{
    on.progress(^(NSNumber *ratio)
    {
        // update progress bar
    });

    on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response)
    {
         if (response == BoxCallbackResponseSuccessful)
         {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is no moot since Box have a completely new iOS SDK (v2.0), which does have the proper progress callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem but we manage to get the answer for this, although we did not try to implement it yet.

> "Currently, the expected method to get progress on file downloads is
>   to register your object as an observer of the download queue ([Box
>   registerObserverForDownloadQueue:self];) and then to extend the
>   BoxObserver protocol and implement any of these callback methods that
>   you are interested in:

```
- (void)downloadDidBeginForItem:(BoxID *)itemID;
- (void)downloadDidProgressForItem:(BoxID *)itemID bytesDownloaded:(NSUInteger)bytes;
- (void)downloadDidCompleteForItem:(BoxID *)itemID withResponse:(BoxCallbackResponse)response;
- (void)downloadDidCompleteForAllItems;
```

> Please remember to remove your object from the observers before you
>   expect your object to be deallocated because observers are currently
>   retained."